# Requests, BeautifulSoup, None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

For some reason I can't seem to find why this code print "None". I copy/pasted the id directly from the HTML... Thanks in advance

```
import bs4
import json
import requests

URL = 'http://hypem.com/popular'

html = requests.get(URL).text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)

print soup.find(id="displayList-data")
```

For some reason it worked when I changed from "requests" to "urllib2"

```
import bs4
import json
import urllib2

URL = 'http://hypem.com/popular/'

html = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
data = soup.find(id="displayList-data")

print data
```

Comment: `print html` and find `displayList-data` in it. If there is no `displayList-data` then page use javascript to load page and you have a lot more job to do.

Comment: I run this code and I get text - `<script>` tag  with JSON data inside.

Comment: When I print html, I can find "displayList-data". But when I print soup I can't find "displayList-data"... I really dont get it. Maybe beaucoup it's between script tags ?

Comment: @alecxe it is there, you forgot the "", search for id="displayList-data"

Answer (score 0):

The code you've pasted works. I do however suspect that you've modified the code that you've pasted compared to what you've tested locally, as `None` sounds like what's returned when you feed the data directly form what you're printing out into `json.loads`. Extract the content of the tag instead, as the text representation of `find(id="...")` includes the `<script>` tags.

```
>>> json.loads(soup.find(id='displayList-data').text)
{u'page_cur': u'/popular', u'title': u'Popular MP3 & Mus ....
```

Comment: This is not working :S, I get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Maybe you have a borked version of bs4 installed, try a pip update or redownload it. It works with the current version from pip and with the HTML served by the site here.